# What's the rule?

Tags: mathematics, pattern

Given the list of ordered pairs:

> (1,1), (2,2), (3,3), (4,4), (5,5), (1,4), (2,4), (1,2), (3,1), (5,1), (3,5)

1 and 2 make 4 laugh, but only 5 makes 1 laugh. What's the rule?

---

I've been staring at this forever. I just can't figure it out. I'm given no further context.

Comment: Based on your comments, it seems that this is not an original puzzle. If so, can you provide the source for it? Puzzles that are not [properly attributed](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) here are generally closed until the attribution is provided. If it is original, then let us know by leaving a comment or editing your post to make that clear. Thanks!

Comment: Are these the only ordered pairs, or is it specified that there could be more?